# How can I prevent the printing of the return value of a closure in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a given html.erb file, I have

```
<%= render "steps_list", :post => @post%>
```

In `_steps_list.html.erb`, I have

```
<%= @post.step_names.each do |step| %>
    Step: <%= "#{step}" %>
<% end %>
```

This works well with one exception. Each step is printed out as I want, but the entire array is also printed out at the end.

`Step: Rinse Step: Lather Step: Repeat RinseLatherRepeat`

I suspect the entire array is printed out at the end because the closure returns the array when it's finished executing.  How do I suppress the printing of the array or the return value of the closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead.

```
<% @post.step_names.each do |step| %>
    Step: <%= "#{step}" %>
<% end %>
```

`<%= ### %>` means "print the output of this".

Comment: D'oh. Newbie here, needless to say.  Thanks. :)