# Suppress closure return value in ruby on rails erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, closures

I have a simple erb template that pulls information from a (Grit) git repository. It displays the information just fine, but it also displays the return value of the closure which is the array of commits I'm iterating through. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648264/how-can-i-prevent-the-printing-of-the-return-value-of-a-closure-in-rails), but the solution does not change my output at all.

```
#controller method for home
def home
  @repo = Repo.new("/home/matt/gitrepo")
end

#home.html.erb
<%= @repo.commits[1..3].each do |commit| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, "#{commit.author}", :class=>"author") %>
<% end %>
```

the page output is

```
Matt Phillips
Matt Phillips
Matt Phillips
[#<Grit::Commit "e761477be972855b0c4273c1c7837baa25178210">, #<Grit::Commit "18140c17632fae7dbf33cdd5e372f96ebe8104de">, #<Grit::Commit "f7e8ee090bb3e8259627179287d1722c328b614f">]
```

How can I suppress the array?

EDIT: Here's what it looks like in irb

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :011 > include Grit
=> Object  
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :012 > @repo = Repo.new("/home/matt/gitrepo")
=> #<Grit::Repo "/home/matt/gitrepo/.git"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :013 > @repo.commits[1..3].each do |commit|
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :014 >     puts commit.author
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :015?>   end
Matt Phillips
Owen Johnson
Matt Phillips
=> [#<Grit::Commit "e761477be972855b0c4273c1c7837baa25178210">, #<Grit::Commit  
"18140c17632fae7dbf33cdd5e372f96ebe8104de">, #<Grit::Commit  
"f7e8ee090bb3e8259627179287d1722c328b614f">] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :016 >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

`<%= @repo.commits[1..3].each do |commit| %>`

to this

`<%- @repo.commits[1..3].each do |commit| %>`

Comment: ok that removed my author lines not the array thats returned at the end of the loop.

Comment: Bizarre. Can you please double-check that what you have pasted in your question matches exactly with your real code?

Comment: Yes, I pasted the code directly from my project. What exactly does `-` do instead of `=` in the script?

Comment: `=` means "print the result of this. `-` won't print the result, and it also suppresses the blank line that you might get from simply using `<% %>`. You want to use `=` in front of your `content_tag` line, but not in front of your loop.

Comment: Ah. Yeah thats what was going on! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*had a ;nil at the end before I realized the = was there*

<%= and <%- both indicate we output the results of the contained Ruby expression.  In the case of your each block the result is the array.

Change to:

```
<% @repo.commits[1..3].each... %>
```

That tells us to not output anything

Comment: That didn't change the output either. Its really strange that I haven't been able to find anyone else thats had this problem with Grit at least...if not erb in general.